# Adobe AIR update framework -- always creating a new desktop icon on update

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm using the AIR update framework (ApplicationUpdaterUI), and whenever the user updates the application, a new desktop icon gets created (overwriting any existing desktop icon there). Is there a way to suppress this behaviour, or can someone suggest a workaround?

Here's the situation:

Our AIR app uses a separate bootstrapping application to launch some services before the AIR application launches, so it's important that the user does not run the AIR executable themselves. Our installer creates a desktop icon that points to the bootstrapping executable. When the user updates the application, it replaces our desktop icon with the AIR shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can override the creation of the standard AIR icon..

Maybe you can configure your helper application as a windows service / unix daemon, launching it automatically on system startup?